# How to create and load a GTK module?

Tags: module, gtk

I want to create a custom GTK module which should be loaded when I start a GTK application.

Documentation on this topic is rare, I searched a lot but I failed to get it running. I'm on Ubuntu Linux with GTK3 and tried sofar:

- Compiled and linked a shared library with the method `void gtk_module_init(gint *argc, gchar ***argv[])` inside. As far as I understood, this should be enough to create a simple module. Full code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void gtk_module_init(gint *argc, gchar ***argv[]) {
    std::cout << "huhu" << std::endl;
}
```

- Put this lib into /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libtest-gtk-module.so
- Tried to launch an application like this: `gnomine --gtk-module=libtest-gtk-module.so` But all I get is: `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "libtest-gtk-module.so"`

**So what else has to be done in order to make GTK load this library?**

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the system aware of the library.  For a library in a system directory, it should be enough to run ldconfig as root.  Take a look at the tutorial [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).

[EDIT]

I got the module to load as follows:

- Since this is C++ code, you need to make sure the function name isn't name mangled:

  ```
  extern "C" {
  void gtk_module_init(gint *argc, gchar ***argv[]) {
      std::cout << "huhu" << std::endl;
  }
  }
  ```
- I built it with the following:

  ```
  g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -olibfoo.so.1.0.1 `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` t.c
  ```
- I used an absolute path to avoid messing with ldconfig, this is probably the best thing to do while developing the module:

  ```
  ~$ gedit --gtk-module=/home/eric/libfoo.so.1.0.1 t.c
  huhu
  ```

This is on Mint LMDE, not Ubuntu, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Well, I tried. But with no success. Maybe there is some mistake in the module? The error provided by GTK is not very helpful... And thanks for the link, it seems rather useful!

Comment: +1 @Simme: Please check the edit. Most likely your problem was with the name mangling issue. You can make use of `readelf` or other such utilities to check if `gtk_module_init` (as is w/o any prefix/suffix i.e. mangling) symbol is present

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with strace:

```
strace -eopen add_your_command_here 2>&1 | grep libtest-gtk-module.so
```

You'll find out where your program is looking for that file.